# Could not load library msvcrt-ruby240.dll

Tags: vim, gvim, ruby

I have installed the last version of the x86 version of vim 8 and I have an issue whith the ruby integration.

My plugins like LustyExplorer can’t work and when I enter `ruby –version` I get the following error :

```
E370: Could not load library msvcrt-ruby240.dll
E266 : Sorry, this command is disabled, the Ruby Library could not be loaded.
```

When I run `:version` I have :

```
+ruby/dyn and -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=24 - DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby240.dll\"
```

Ruby is installed in `C:\Ruby24` and the bin folder containing the `msvcrt-ruby240.dll` is in `%PATH%`.

I also tried to put in my `vimrc` file:

```
set rubydll='C:\Ruby24\bin\msvcrt-ruby240.dll'
```

but I got the following error:

```
E370: Could not load Library 
E266 : Sorry, this command is disabled, the Ruby Library could not be loaded. Both ruby and vim are x86.
```

I am working on windows 10.

Comment: Sometimes the Windows %PATH% doesn't properly initialize unless you log out and back into your Windows user account. Also, is your Vim 32 or 64 bit? If the latter, it may not be able to run the 32bit version of the Ruby DLL. (On my system it's `C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby240.dll`.)

Comment: and another duplicate one: [vim-use](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/FfrXPI8V84E), [vim issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2660), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915343/could-not-load-library-msvcrt-ruby240-dll), [vim-win32-installer issue](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/issues/47)